# Base Page with Layout for Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, custom-controls

I am trying to define a common base page for all of my Windows Phone 7 pages that includes a common place for derived pages to add their markup, similar to content placeholders in ASP.NET.

So far the code samples I have seen all add code behavior, but none show how I can use a base page to do the following:

- place the application title in the top left corner
- place the company logo in the top right corner
- have a dynamic (meaning the user can change it) background image

I can define a custom MyTitleControl to achieve most of the items above, but I would still have to rely on all the page referencing it (rather than deriving from a common base page). Is this even possible in WP7?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that with a base page class is to use "loaded" event or better method OnNavigatedTo and change visual tree as needed.

PhoneApplicationPage Class derives from UserControl, so it's visual tree is built using InitializeComponent auto-generated method.
It's generated to read XAML and instantiate controls and set root control as a Content of current user control (in this scenario Page).

So you might use it later (not in ctor) or modify tree after this method.

Another option might be creating Style for page and just applying it to all pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is a limitation of WP7.

Every WP7 app has a single instance of PhoneApplicationFrame associated with it. Everytime the current page changes, the PhoneApplicationFrame 'Content' property is set to the PhoneApplicationPage. And a PhoneApplicationPage does not support additional PhoneApplicationPages inside.

The only way to accomplish something similar, is to convert all of your pages to UserControls, and ensure there is only one PhoneApplicationPage .

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from PhoneApplicationPage and give your new class additional properties, a new default Style, a new Template - after all a page is nothing but a UserControl with custom properties.

Then alter your myPage.xaml.cs and myPage.xaml files to inherit from your new class instead of from PhoneApplicationPage.